# Proof by using Double counting

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

How to use the hint to complete the proof.
A hint from the textbook is :
Consider a club has n junior members and n senior members.  A committee with n members is to be formed with a president from the senior members.

Comment: Double counting means finding two combinatorial descriptions of the same thing: counting one way would give the expression on the left, and the other way the right. This is one way to prove equalities.

Answer (score 2):

*Double counting* in this context means showing that the expressions on the two sides of the equation count the same thing in two different ways and therefore must be equal. In this case it helps to rewrite the equation as

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk\binom{n}k\binom{n}{n-k}=n\binom{2n-1}{n-1}\,.$$

HINT: You have a pool of $n$ women and $n$ men from which you wish to choose a team of $n$ people that includes at least one woman and appoint one of the women captain on the team captain.

- Suppose that you decide to have $k$ women on the team. What are the possible values of $k$? In how many ways can you choose such a team if you choose $k$ women, choose one of those women to be captain, and then fill out the team by choosing $n-k$ of the men?
- In how many ways can you choose such a team if you first choose one of the women to be captain and then choose $n-1$ of the remaining people to fill out the team?